# Grab words out of arrays

Tags: java, arrays, artificial-intelligence

I am extremely unsure of how to do this. I understand (I believe) that you use

```
String[] user {"stuff","other stuff","more stuff"};
```

I'm developing a chat bot and I need it to be able to recognize what the user said and if it's inside of the array (it's "database," per say), then it will respond accordingly.

Something simple so that I could be able to say, "How are you?" And it would look for "How are you?" or something at least close to it and respond accordingly with a random positive word. I've achieved this function by simply using lots of if-else statements, but this is far too much coding.

Comment: I think what you are looking for here is natural language processing and that can't really be explained in a thread on stack overflow. I'd venture a guess you could get something simple going with regex though, regular expressions. That again is kind of a big subject. Try googling "regular expresions in java" to start

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want your bot to respond to some prompt from the user. In that case, you could use a `Map<String, String>` to store query-answer pairs.

```
Map<String, String> answers = new HashMap<String, String>();

answers.put("How are you?", "Great!");
answers.put("Where is the cake?", "The cake is a lie");
```

and then just check whether the query string is in answers:

```
public String answerUser(String query) {
    if (answers.containsKey(query)) {
        return answers.get(query);
    } else {
        return "I don't understand.";
    }
}
```

If you want more than one possible answer, use a `Map<String, List<String>>` and select randomly from the list:

```
public String answerUser(String query) {
    Random rand = new Random();

    if (answers.containsKey(query)) {
        List<String> ans = answers.get(query);
        int id = rand.nextInt(ans.size());
        return ans.get(id);
    } else {
        return "I don't understand.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very big and complicated subject, and you haven't really posted enough to go on.

To split a string into words use `String#split()`, that will give you the array you want. (you probably want to split on all non-alpha, or all whitespace).

You then want to define keywords that your AI responds to, and scan the array for any of those keywords.

Use some sort of scoring system to then determine the appropriate response.

For example you could have a HashMap of String to a class that has both a weight and a meaning. Go through the sentence, sum up the scores for every action you find. Take appropriate decisions based on the combined values.

That's a very simple algorithm and much better ones are possible but they are a lot harder and this will get you started.

Comment: Thank you, for all of these. The weighted responses seems like a very good idea, and I've already had an idea kind of like that (though I couldn't properly get my thoughts together on it, so thank you) for adding in simulated emotions, weighing user input on what the setting is to determine how the AI "feels".

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list instead of array, which will give you the contains() method.  For instance:

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
words.add("Hello");
words.add("bye");
if(words.contains("hello")) {
    //do something 
}
```

Another option would be to map the phrase to the response:

```
Map<String, String> wordMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
wordMap.put("How are you?", "Great");
wordMap.put("Where are you?", "Work");
wordMap.get("How are you?");
```

Combine these and map a phrase to a list of responses if you want.

Answer (score 0):

An intelligent chat bot would need a lot more design, but if you just wanted a solution where *"I say this, then you say that"* than you could do it a couple ways.

**Using Two Arrays**

Since you know how to use one array, Figured I'd start here for simplicity.

```
String[] userInput {"how are you", "how are you?", "how you doing?"};
String[] response {"good", "terrible", "is that a joke?"};

//Go through each userInput string and see if it matches what you typed in.
    //If it matches, print the corresponding position in the response array.
```

**Using a Map**

Same idea, but is a collection that is more suited for the situation.

```
Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<String, String>();
response.add("how are you", "good");

//When you receive input, check the response map using the input as the key.
//Return the value as the response.
//Better documented in sebii's answer.
```